# Downloading a Windows driver on 13.10

Tags: hardware

How would I go about downloading a windows driver, such as WNA 3100 to Ubuntu 13.10? I was unaware that I would be unable to use my wireless card upon installing it onto my computer before I had done so already.

Comment: You cannot use windows drivers. Please update your question to include details on your wireless card (make model etc) so someone can direct you to a solution specific to you.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows driver isn't going to work on Ubuntu.  You'll need to find a Linux driver for your device, and either use your Ethernet port or copy it to a USB stick.